# Nested columns are too small in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When I try to nest two col-md-2 columns inside a col-md-4 column, the nested columns are too small, more like md-1 or less.  I have used a row inside the outer tag as suggested by the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting).  I tried changing all the "md" to "lg" and "sm", but that didn't make any difference.  How can I make my second row of nested inputs line up with my first row of non-nested inputs?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

[Jsfiddle version (resize the result pane so that the controls are beside each other)](https://jsfiddle.net/fx2mbf4e/1/)

```
<div class="container" id="content">
    <form>        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">Label
            <input value="nonnested input">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Label
            <input value="nonnested input">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            Label across two inputs, Label across two inputs
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input value="nested input 1" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input value="nested input 2" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I get it now!  The nested columns need to total to 12 to fill the width of the outer tag.  So my second set of inputs should read like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    Label across two inputs, Label across two inputs
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <input value="nested input 1" >
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <input value="nested input 2" >
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```